# Embed workflow/monad in another workflow/monad?

Tags: f#, computation-expression

For example, I have a workflow for logging, and I want to use async in the logging workflow. How to call logging's `bind` in async workflow?

```
log {
    async {
       let! a = .... // Need to do logging here.
       let! b = .... // Need to do async here
```

*Edit:* I heard that it's a good idea to use workflow to replace AOP for cross cutting concerns purpose in F#. I'm not sure how to handle the embedding issues. Or it's not a good idea to use workflow for it?

Comment: Just out of purity, the native F# name for this construct is a computation expression rather than a monad

Comment: There was a similar question some time ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129277/can-i-use-different-workflows-simultaneously-in-f

Answer (score 5):

F# does not have any automated way of doing this. What you essentially want is to create a composed computation that captures two different behaviors. The best way to do this is to define a new computation, say `asyncLog`, that lets you do both of the things you need. This is not easy, but the following are good starting points:

- [The `asyncSeq` computation](http://tomasp.net/blog/async-sequences.aspx/) shows how to create asynchronous sequences
- [The ExtCore library](https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore) has a couple of computations composed like this

In reality, you do not need to do this *that* often in F#, because there are not that many computation expressions to compose.

In your example, you're using `async` and `log`. Although logging makes for a great demo when explaining how computation expressions work, I'm not sure that I would use computation expressions to add logging to my application in practice - it seems easier to just use a global logger object and call it directly (but it really depends on what your `log` computation does behind the covers).

Comment: I just use logging as an example here. (I heard that monad/computation expression is better than AOP for logging from an  F# guy) As for composite computation, I may, take loggin/async example, only need to log some statements and async call some other statements, maybe both for some statements. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AsyncReader computation expression for this https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore/blob/master/ExtCore/Control.fs#L1769 and lift Asyncs and Readers if you need.